# Disable creating nested objects in django rest framework

Tags: django, angularjs, foreign-key-relationship, django-rest-framework

Hi,

Can you help me how to **disable creating nested objects** ?

I have serializers like this:

**(Employee has ForeignKey to Team)**

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('id', 'name')
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'surname', 'team')
        depth = 1
```

or instead could be:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = TeamSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'surname', 'team')
```

when i post json (create employee)

```
{
    name: "name",
    surname: "surname",
    team: {
           id: 1,
           name: "Web Team"
          }
}
```

object employee creates but also object team...
is there any way to disable creating team object together with employee ?
i just want to create employee and set selected team (curently in database) to employee

And on GET (list) i would like to be able to retrieve
data like:

```
{
 name: "name",
 surname: "surname",
 team: {
    id: 1,
    name: "Web Team"
 }
```

not like that

```
{
 name: "name",
 surname: "surname",
 team: 1
}
```

Is there any way to to that in django rest framework (also iam using angular)

Regards

### **UPDATE**

Currently serializers:

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = TeamSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
```

I cant use serializers.RelatedField() because it's returned only **unicode** I need 'id' and 'name' (i suppose)

this is my POST json: ( Restangular.all('employee').post(data) )

```
data: {
        name: "emp1",
        photo: "",
        skype: "",
        surname: "qweqwe",
        team: {
              id: 1,
              name: "Web",
        }
}
```

and DRF returned json:

```
employee: {
    id: 2,
    name: "emp1",
    photo: "",
    skype: "",
    surname: "qweqwe",
    team: {
        id:3, <-- NEW ID!
        name: "Web"
    }   
}
```

so yea, i am sure that new team objects created. So what now ?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem:

```
class ReadEmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = TeamSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'surname', 'team',)


class WriteEmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def from_native(self, data, files):
        data['team'] = data['team']['id']
        return serializers.ModelSerializer.from_native(self, data, files)

    def to_native(self, obj):
        return ReadEmployeeSerializer(obj).data

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'surname', 'team',)
```

post/put method use primary key (WriteEmployeeSerializer) - before replace dict to primary key

get method use full object (ReadEmployeeSerializer)

Answer (score 2):

I found that `ModelSerializer.to_native()` and `ModelSerializer.from_native()` don't exist in the latest version of DRF. I came up with the following derived from the accepted solution:

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'team')

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # If team is not a dict, such as when submitting via the Browseable UI, this would fail.
        try:
            data['team'] = data['team']['id']
        except TypeError:
            pass
        return super(PlayerSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return ReadPlayerSerializer(instance).data


class ReadPlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = TeamSerializer()

    class Meta(PlayerSerializer.Meta):
        pass
```

Effectively, it seems that `from_native` is now `to_representation`, and `to_native` is no `to_internal_value`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first of all, are you sure that your nested object is created? Because DRF was not designed to create nested objects, so this is a very strange behavior (more precisely, this is a [work in progress](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/395), as stated by its creator, Tom Christie).

Then, in order to have the serializer representation that you want, you must follow some rules:

1. Create a simple serializer for each model (just like in your first code snippet)
2. Add the FK relationship on the EmployeeSerializer: (be careful, for this to work, you must have your FK named 'team')
   team = serializers.RelatedField()
3. Add the ManyToOne relationship on your TeamSerializer: (this is only needed if you also want to have all your employees when you get a Team object; if not, you can skip this part)
   employees = EmployeeSerializer(required=False, many=True)

Also, you should remove the *depth* attribute from your serializer, he is the one that flattens your serialization (or you can just set it to 2). Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

View for multiple serializers:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        return ReadEmployeeSerializer
    elif self.request.method == 'POST':
        return WriteEmployeeSerializer
    else:
        return DefaultSerializer

class WriteEmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'surname', 'team')

class ReadEmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = TeamSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'surname', 'team')
```

A bit redundant, but should do the job.

Comment: That's look ok but if i create new employee then your view return data with id instead of full team object