# SerializerClass field on Serializer save from primary key

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am working developing an API with Django-rest-framework and consuming it from a web app. It has a Physician Model  with a Fk from the django.auth User model. I want to post from a form to the Physician Model but the serializer returns this message:

> {"user":{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got unicode."]}}

I am sending the primary key of the user object. Which is the right (or just one way) to store a foreign key on DRF. I have tried overriding get_validation_exclusions on the serializer and overriding perform_create method on the viewset.

The api and the web app are decouple. The API is developed with django and the web app with angularjs.

My model

```
class Physician(models.Model):
    medical_office_number = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    fiscal_id_number = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.first_name +' '+ self.user.last_name
```

Serializer:

```
class PhysicianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = AccountSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Physician
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'medical_office_number', 'fiscal_id_number')
        read_only_fields = ('id')
        depth = 1
    def get_validation_exclusions(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exclusions = super(PhysicianSerializer, self).get_validation_exclusions()
        return exclusions + ['user']
```

*Edit
This is my account serializer, which is based on this implementation and with the @Kevin Brown suggestion

```
class PrimaryKeyNestedMixin(serializers.RelatedField, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField.to_internal_value(self, data)
    def to_representation(self, data):
        return serializers.ModelSerializer.to_representation(self, data)

class AccountSerializer(PrimaryKeyNestedMixin):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
                  'first_name', 'last_name', 'password',
                  'confirm_password', 'is_admin',)
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)
```

Viewset

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
```

When I try to serializer this object, it triggers an error.

So I can post any user from the `<select>` element. But I can't verify the solution. Something I am missing?

Error Stacktrace

```
TypeError at /api/v1/accounts/

__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)

Exception Location:     /home/jlromeroc/workspace/asclepios/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py in many_init, line 68
Python Executable:  /home/jlromeroc/workspace/asclepios/venv/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3

File "/home/jlromeroc/workspace/asclepios/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 111. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/home/jlromeroc/workspace/asclepios/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view 57. return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jlromeroc/workspace/asclepios/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view 85. return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jlromeroc/workspace/asclepios/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch 407. response = self.handle_exception(exc) File "/home/jlromeroc/workspace/asclepios/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch 404. response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jlromeroc/workspace/asclepios/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list 45. serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, many=True)
File "/home/jlromeroc/workspace/asclepios/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in get_serializer 90. instance, data=data, many=many, partial=partial, context=context File "/home/jlromeroc/workspace/asclepios/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in __new__ 48. return cls.many_init(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jlromeroc/workspace/asclepios/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in many_init 68. list_kwargs = {'child_relation': cls(*args, **kwargs)}

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/v1/accounts/
Exception Value: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)
```

Edit**
I have opted to override the create function on the viewset and include the object in the request, so it can be validated, but then, the serializer tries to insert a new object for the Account model. How can I prevent this behaviour? I tried to set the serializer on the PhysicianSerializer class as read_only but then, django tries to store the model with a null user_id. How can I save a model without try to insert an related object too?

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that with nested serializers, Django REST framework is expecting both the input and the output to be a nested representation. DRF will automatically validate the input to make sure it matches the nested serializer, allowing you to create the main object and any relations in a single request.

You are looking to have a nested output with a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` input. This is very common for those who don't need to create relations in the same request, but instead will always be using existing objects in their relations. The way you are going to have to do it is basically take in a primary key (just like a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`) in `to_internal_value`, but output a serializer in `to_representation`. Something like this (untested) should work

```
class PrimaryKeyNestedMixin(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField.to_internal_value(self, data)

    def to_representation(self, data):
        return serializers.ModelSerializer.to_representation(self, data)
```

You would need to use this as a mixin on the nested serializer, `AccountSerializer` in your case, and it *should* do what you are looking for.

Comment: and that's valid for all serializers who are a fk on another serializer? It seems a odd approach for a quite normal situation. if you have a <select> with users or some other object which is a fk on the model you are posting, given the fact that you are using an api, it's a common scenario. I might be missing something

Comment: Either way, your answer looks promising. Thanks

Comment: Not working, I got Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, or set read_only=`True`. if I use the Serializer class as a field.

Comment: Try setting `queryset=Account.objects.all()` when you are setting the `AccountSerializer` field on the `PhysicianSerializer`.

Comment: The __init__ error could be the viewset model? It inherits from ModelViewSet, but the serializer inherits from the mixin.

Comment: Right, I need to look more into this and figure out what the custom `__init__` should be. Though just for starters, try swapping the base models in `PrimaryKeyNestedMixin` so the serializer is first.

Comment: Did that, but now I get Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, or set read_only=`True`, with the queryset argument set in PhysicianSerializer, I don't know where is it.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem (wanting to POST id / FK of the object, but expecting the serialized object in a GET). I implemented [Kevin Brown's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016439/2689986) successfully for my case. Adapting that to your problem (too late, but hope someone else, including future me, stumbles on this and finds it useful).

```
def get_primary_key_related_model(model_class, **kwargs):
    """
    Nested serializers are a mess. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016439/2689986
    This lets us accept ids when saving / updating instead of nested objects.
    Representation would be into an object (depending on model_class).
    """
    class PrimaryKeyNestedMixin(model_class):

        def to_internal_value(self, data):
            try:
                return model_class.Meta.model.objects.get(pk=data)
            except model_class.Meta.model.DoesNotExist:
                self.fail('does_not_exist', pk_value=data)
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                self.fail('incorrect_type', data_type=type(data).__name__)

        def to_representation(self, data):
            return model_class.to_representation(self, data)

    return PrimaryKeyNestedMixin(**kwargs)


class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        # ...


class PhysicianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = get_primary_key_related_model(AccountSerializer)

    class Meta:
        model = Physician
        # ...
```

The `class` generator comes very handy when you have custom serializer fields (restricting access based on request.user).

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I followed this answer from SO. [Disable creating nested objects in django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088473/disable-creating-nested-objects-in-django-rest-framework) Its a little bit messy, but works. Either way, that's something it lacks DRF.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by having different views to handle get single item and post, and get nested list. The get single item and get list used a nested serializer and the post method used a non-nested serializer. When posting to create a new job alert you can use the primary keys for the job and the user which are the related objects.

```
class JobAlertList(APIView):
    """
    List all job alerts or create a new job alert
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        job_alerts = JobAlert.objects.all()
        serializer = JobAlertNestedSerializer(job_alerts, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = JobAlertSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class JobAlertDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve or delete a job alert instance.
    """
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return JobAlert.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except JobAlert.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        job_alert = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = JobAlertNestedSerializer(job_alert)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        job_alert = self.get_object(pk)
        job_alert.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

class JobAlertSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = JobAlert
        fields = ('job', 'user')
        depth = 0

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data.pop('user')
        job = validated_data.pop('job')
        job_alert = JobAlert.objects.create(user=user, job=job)
        return job_alert


class JobAlertNestedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = JobAlert
        fields = ('id', 'job', 'user')
        depth = 1

url(r'^job_alerts/$', views.JobAlertList.as_view(), name='job-alerts-list'),
url(r'^job_alerts/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.JobAlertDetail.as_view(), name='job-alerts-detail'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Field type that tries to solve the problem of the Data Save requests with its ForeignKey in Integer, and the requests to read data with nested data

This is the class:

```
class NestedRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
"""
    Model identical to PrimaryKeyRelatedField but its
    representation will be nested and its input will
    be a primary key.
"""

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.pk_field = kwargs.pop('pk_field', None)
    self.model = kwargs.pop('model', None)
    self.serializer_class = kwargs.pop('serializer_class', None)
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

def to_representation(self, data):
    pk = super(NestedRelatedField, self).to_representation(data)
    try:
        return self.serializer_class(self.model.objects.get(pk=pk)).data
    except self.model.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def to_internal_value(self, data):
    return serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField.to_internal_value(self, data)
```

And so it would be used:

```
class PostModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    message = NestedRelatedField(
         queryset=MessagePrefix.objects.all(),
         model=MessagePrefix,
         serializer_class=MessagePrefixModelSerializer
   )
```

I hope this helps you.