# Serializer ForeignKey results in "Expected a dictionary ..."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My Model:

```
class Font(ValidateVersionOnSaveMixin, models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)


class Glyph(ValidateVersionOnSaveMixin, models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=True)  
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    font = models.ForeignKey(Font, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to post the following JSON to add a Glyph to an already existing Font (having the `fontId` as ID) object.

```
{
  fontId: "4a14a055-3c8a-43ba-aab3-221b4244ac73"
  id: "40da7a83-a204-4319-9a04-b0a544bf4440"
  unit: "aaa"
}
```

As there is a mismatch between the ForeignKey Field `font` and the JSON property`fontId` I am adding `source='font'` in my Serializer:

```
class FontSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Font
        fields = ('id', 'name')


class GlyphSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fontId = FontSerializer(source='font')
    class Meta:
        model = Glyph
        fields = ('id', 'unit', 'fontId' )
```

But the result is an BAD REQUEST Error:

```
{"fontId":{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."]}}
```

---

**Update**

The following Serializer gave me the result I was looking for.

```
class GlyphSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fontId = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Font.objects.all(),
        required=True,
        source='font',
        write_only=False
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Glyph
        fields = ('id', 'unit', 'version', 'fontId')
```

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010663/serializerclass-field-on-serializer-save-from-primary-key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SerializerClass field on Serializer save from primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010663/serializerclass-field-on-serializer-save-from-primary-key)

Answer (score 3):

You can user **model_to_dict** method as bellow:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
model_to_dict(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `fontId` as being a serialized object (FontSerializer). But that serializer in turn is defined as having both an id and a name. Where as your json dictionary is posting only an id. You would have to change that to a dictionary that contains both an id and a name

```
{
  fontId: {id: "4a14a055-3c8a-43ba-aab3-221b4244ac73",name: "some name" },
  id: "40da7a83-a204-4319-9a04-b0a544bf4440"
  unit: "aaa"
}
```

Comment: The font already exists. I want to add a glyph to this font with my JSON. Is there a way to do this without changing the JSON?

Comment: sorry for delay. Missed the notification. Did you manage to sort this out or do you still need this input form me?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is that during deserialization process, DRF calls `.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` before you can call `serializer.save(validated_data)`. And `non_field_errors` lists any general validation errors during this process. In your `GlyphSerializer`, your `FontSerializer` is a nested serializer, which correlates to a Python dictionary. So it will raise an error like you encountered for any non-dictionary data types.

You could create a subclass of `GlyphSerializer` called `GlyphCreateSerializer`

```
class FontSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Font
        fields = ('id', 'name')


class GlyphSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fontId = FontSerializer(source='font')
    class Meta:
        model = Glyph
        fields = ('id', 'unit', 'fontId' )

class GlyphCreateSerializer(GlyphSerializer):
    fontId = serializers.CharField()
```

And you can use `GlyphCreateSerializer` for the POST request on your Viewset.

Comment: how you can define to use GlyphCreateSerializer on POST and GlyphSerializer on get? And i need to define an extra for update/delete?